# HTTP 404 error while trying to debug MVC 2 application page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tried creating a default MVC 2 application using the visual studio template and while setting up start page and browsing the application getting the http 404 (Resource not found error), have checked the controller classes for the naming conventions and also the option to set specific page in the project properties.

Kindly advice for any options to try out and also as I am new to MVC, so any help is highly appreciated.

Error Message

HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Hi, I am using the basic web template of Asp.Net MVC 2 Web Application template available in Visual Studio 2010 and have set up the start page.

Below the brief description of the error

### Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Views/Account/LogOn.aspx

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1022

Do let me know if any additional information is required.

Regards
Arvind

Comment: can u please provide some code and show error page.

Comment: Hi Jinesh,I did not share the code because it was just the basic version where I was getting the error while trying to browse the start-up page.

Comment: plz edit that link in your browser from `/Views/Account/LogOn.aspx` to `/Account/LogOn` then hit ENTER

Comment: Hi Bellash, even tried that but it did not work. - Got it from Visual Studio by debugging the same.

Comment: Hi, Can anyone advise on the above error..

Answer (score 0):

Move:

```
/Views/Account/LogOn.aspx
```

To:

```
 /LogOn.aspx
```

MVC uses routing to get to the `Views` folder. If you want to use legacy `aspx` HTTP handlers move it to the root folder.

Comment: Hi have tried moving the aspx file from the project's view folder to outside but still no luck. Even the routing information is added in the Global.asax file for the index .aspx but still I am not able to browse while debugging .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it by this way:

In a first time, you have to check if your project configuration is correct:
Right click on the project properties, check if everything is ok.

Next, remove the file applicationhost.config. Visual Studio will re-create it automatically. You should find it in the folder "path_project/.vs/config" in the same folder of your project.